# There exists some $M>0$ and $r>0$ where if $x\in(a-r,a+r)-\{a\}$ then $|f(x)|\leq M\cdot |x-a|^2$ Now calculate the limit: $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$

Tags: calculus, limits, functions

There exists some $M>0$ and $r>0$ where if $x\in(a-r,a+r)-\{a\}$ then $|f(x)|\leq M\cdot |x-a|^2$

Now calculate the limit: $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$

We know that $\forall x\in(a-r,a+r)-\{a\}$ fulfills $0<|x-a|<r$, then $|x-a|^2<r^2$

Then for any $x$ in that interval: $|f(x)|\leq M\cdot |x-a|^2<Mr^2$

How to choose epsilon and delta so the limit definition holds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that if $0 < \delta < r$ and also $0 < \delta < \sqrt{\dfrac{ \epsilon}{M}}$ then $$|x-a| < \delta \implies |f(x) - 0| = |f(x)| \le M|x-a|^2 < M \delta^2 < \epsilon.$$
For arbitrary $\epsilon > 0$ you can select $\delta = \min \left\{ r, \sqrt{\dfrac{ \epsilon}{M}} \right\}$.